# visualizar palabras con tílde en cmd

Tags: python, json, cmd, consola

Quisiera saber como hacer que se muestren palabras con tilde desde la consola de windows. Estoy haciendo un programa en el que se pega un texto ya definido al porta papeles pero si hay palabras con tilde las muestra raras. por ejemplo:

```
import json
with open('textos/textos.json') as a:
    mensaje = json.load(a)

print(mensaje['saludo'])
```

Saludo es un texto muy largo que lo puse en json para no tener un codigo inmenso de puro texto y lo mando a llamar. por ejemplo en el json saludo es `{saludo:"múchás pálábrá cón tílde"}` (es un ejemplo muy exagerado pero es para ejemplificar)

y luego print(mensaje['saludo'])

y la salida por consola es la siguiente: mÃºchÃ¡s pÃ¡lÃ¡brÃ¡ cÃ³n tÃ­lde

tengo la leve sospecha de que se debe a que lo mando a traer de un archivo json pero solo se python.

Comment: Problema sencillo: codificación de python, problema más complicado: codificación de tu Sistema Operativo

Comment: tu problema es un problema que no se puede reproducir, lo he probado y todo me sale bien

Comment: Probablemente tenga que ver con la codificación que usas para guardar el fuente de tu programa. Yo trabajo todo en "utf-8" y cero problemas.